# Laptop keyboard keys are pressed automatically

Tags: drivers, keyboard, hardware-failure

I know that's being asked but I can't find a solution for my problem.

I have old Asus EeePc notebook with windows XP Home SP3 x86

From time to time (few seconds up to few minutes) it acts like the right arrow key is being held down, and stops that behavior when left or up arrows or backspace is pressed, but sometimes starts again when down or right arrow is pressed, while right arrow is not functioning at all most of the time. Also no '#' sign, though other like '$' '%' e.g. work perfectly fine. Bad explanation but I think you get the point.

How to find out if it's a software problem or not? I have tried to update the keyboard driver and uninstall the keyboard with no success (shows the keyboard as unrecognized but it's still usable and the problem persists)

And yeah, this don't interfere with typing, just everything tends to scroll down/left

Comment: " (shows the keyboard as unrecognized but it's still usable and the problem persists)": What makes you think the keyboard is usable?

Comment: Sounds to me more like a hardware problem.

Comment: What makes you think the keyboard is usable? I use it to type :)

Comment: Also no '#' sign,